# CVS checkout returning mostly empty files

Tags: checkout, cvs

Running the following command

> cvs -d C:\CVSfolder checkout .

But many of the files it exports are empty. 0 bytes.
The CVS folder is 13.7GB but the checkout is around 800MB.
Yes CVS folder should be larger but 800MB is way too small for the files we have.

Comment: Looks like I need to export, not checkout?

Comment: Now running "cvs -d C:\CVSfolder export -f -D now module" and still getting a lot of empty files.

Comment: -kb tag fixed the issue. Though CVSNT is crashing on some files. Just my luck. xd